# Count condition in Excel

Tags: excel, count, excel-formula, countif

I have a range of people that is labeled as `D`, `E`, `F`, and `NEW`
in each one they could be a `condition` *yes* or *no*.

I am trying to figure out how to count someone that is a `D` and a `condition` *yes*

I know it has to do with `Countif` or `countifs` but not sure how to do that

Comment: Please post an example and what you have tried so far

Comment: I think your question is not about programming and there is not any tried code that we could help you on it, So migrate your question to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) site, It will make more sense there ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming** values 'D', 'E', 'F', 'New' are in **column A** and condition 'Yes' or 'No' in **column B**, you would use:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,"D",$B:$B,"Yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data starts in column A with the person name, you could try the following.

```
 =COUNTIFS(B:B,"Yes",E:E,"Yes")
```

It's basically looking for a "Yes in column B (which relates to D) and "Yes" in column E (which relates to New).

Adjust the columns in my formula depending on your data.